# Rails Nokogiri xpath().each only storing first node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xml-parsing, nokogiri

I'm trying to import ~10K of XML nodes into my Rails DB as records via a database seed. Here's my code to import the XML code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read("./db/seed/recipes.xml"))

doc.xpath('//Item').each do |i|
  Recipe.find_or_create_by_title(title: i.xpath('title').inner_text)
end
```

and sample XML data:

```
<Item>
  <title>Fried Eggs and Collard Greens Over Polenta</title>
</Item>
```

Yet when I try to seed it only seeds the first node (even though there are 15k). I'm a total XML noob. Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: Note that you can simplify the above with: `doc.xpath('//Item/title').each{ |t| create_by_title title:t.text }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML documents must contain one element that is the parent of all other elements. E.g.,

```
<Items>
  <Item>
    <title>Fried Eggs and Collard Greens Over Polenta</title>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <title>Fried Eggs and Collard Greens Over Polenta</title>
  </Item>
</Items>
```